# Turn Get-WebBinding output into New-WebBinding commands

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

As part of a deployment script, I want to save all the bindings currently on a web site -- but I want to save them in a format that can be used to recreate them later.

So far I have this:

```
    Import-module WebAdministration
    (Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$siteName).Bindings.Collection | select-object @{ Label="CMD"; Expression={"New-WebBinding -name '{0}' -Protocol {1} -IPAddress '{2}' -Port {3} -HostHeader '{4}'" -f "#siteName",$_.protocol,$_.bindingInformation.split(":")[0],$_.bindingInformation.split(":")[1],$_.bindingInformation.split(":")[2]}} | findstr "New-WebBinding" >c:\temp\bindings-$siteName.ps1
```

This produces useful output like this:

```
New-WebBinding -name 'w2pclient' -Protocol http -IPAddress '172.16.7.17' -Port 80 -HostHeader ''   
New-WebBinding -name 'w2pclient' -Protocol http -IPAddress '172.16.7.16' -Port 80 -HostHeader ''   
New-WebBinding -name 'w2pclient' -Protocol https -IPAddress '172.16.7.18' -Port 443 -HostHeader '' 
New-WebBinding -name 'w2pclient' -Protocol https -IPAddress '172.16.7.36' -Port 443 -HostHeader ''
```

Unfortunately as you can see there are two things missing regarding the SSL bindings:

- The thumbprint of the certificate (`-Thumbprint` parameter for `New-WebBinding`)
- What kind of SSL binding it is (`-SslFlags` parameter for `New-WebBinding`)

I started poking around with the `dir IIS:\\SslBindings` as an alternative, and I see how it can get me the `Thumbprint` but not the `SslFlags`.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] Jan Chrbolka gave me the answer. Here's my final script:

```
function Record-Bindings([string]$siteName)
{
    Import-module WebAdministration
    (Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$siteName).Bindings.Collection | 
      Select-Object bindinginformation, Protocol, @{ name="IP"; expression={$_.bindinginformation.split(":")[0]}}, 
     @{name="Port"; expression={$_.bindinginformation.split(":")[1]}}, 
     @{name="HostName"; expression={$_.bindinginformation.split(":")[2]}},
     @{name="certificateHash"; expression={$_.GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")}},
     @{name="sslFlags"; expression={$_.GetAttributeValue("sslFlags")}} | 
     Where-Object {$_.Port -lt 8000} |
     ForEach-Object { "New-WebBinding -name '{0}' -Protocol {1} -IPAddress '{2}' -Port {3} -HostHeader '{4}' -Thumbprint '{5}' -SslFlags {6}" `
     -f "$siteName",$_.protocol,$_.IP, $_.Port, $_.HostName, $_.certificateHash, $_.sslFlags } > c:\temp\bindings-$siteName.ps1

}
```

Comment: The values you need are in the Bindings.Collection. You need to use the **GetAttributeValue** method to retrieve them. Something like this... `(Get-Item IIS:\Sites\TEST).Bindings.Collection[1].GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")` and `(Get-Item IIS:\Sites\TEST).Bindings.Collection[1].GetAttributeValue("sslFlags")`

Comment: Excellent! I probably would have figured that out if I'd realized one machine I was testing on was actually Windows 2008 instead of 2012.... Enter that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values for the parameters you need are located in the Bindings.Collection.

You need to use the **GetAttributeValue** method to retrieve them.

Something like this...

```
(Get-Item IIS:\Sites\TEST).Bindings.Collection[1].GetAttributeValue("certificateHash")
(Get-Item IIS:\Sites\TEST).Bindings.Collection[1].GetAttributeValue("sslFlags")
```